# Criteria for NARQ

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, not-a-real-question

I'm confused why this question was closed as Not A Real Question (NARQ):
[Why can't I explicitly cast an int to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320483/why-doesnt-this-work-int-to-string)

What should we be looking for to determine what isn't a question on SO? To me this post has:

- A very clear problem: Why does implicit conversion vs. explicit conversion of types not work?
- Well-defined error encountered
- Code to support the problem
- A simple and focused question

Is this just a case of close votes gaining momentum? It's a shame if posts like these are not welcome so I'm trying to get a better idea of what the community finds wrong with it.

Comment: It's been reopened.

Comment: @Shawn: +1 for the rest of the community in that case, but the question still remains - it's my personal *feeling* that it shouldn't have generated close votes to begin with. So I'm looking for valid reasons why users would have wanted it closed. I hope this question can generate some feedback in that sense.

Comment: @Yuck: I'm only speaking as a layman here, but the generic title "Why doesn't this work?" of the original question might play a role here. Moreover, I find that Michael Mrozek's edit improved the question a lot.

Comment: @Hendrik: You're right that the most recent edit does clean up the question. Its essence was still well-founded, I believe. The question title **was** definitely pretty bad. Still have to open the question in order to vote-close..

Comment: @Yuck: I wasn't trying to judge whether the close votes were justified or not, just trying to shed some light on "reasons why users would have wanted it closed". (I haven't thought about whether the reasons are _valid_, so only posted this as a comment `:-)`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree that in its current form it's a valid question.

However, looking at the pre-edited version, it does at first glance look like the typical NARQ question we see so often on SO, i.e.:
*"Why doesn't this work?"* 
followed by `<block of code>` without much explanation or an error message.

I wouldn't be surprised if someone glanced at it and instinctively voted to close. Once a few votes have been clocked, it only reinforces the stereotype of a bad question and *POW*!

Answer (score 11):

Did you read the [original revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7320483/1)?  It was asking why a piece of code didn't work without really explaining what "work" would mean.